# When running unit tests on objects(s) whose purpose it is to track various lengths of elapsed time, is there any way to speed up the process?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, tdd

**Longform Question:**

When running unit tests on objects(s) whose purpose it is to track various lengths of elapsed time, is there any way to speed up the process rather than having to sit through it? In essence, if there’s a unit test that would take sixty or more seconds to complete, is there a way to simulate that test in one or two seconds. I don’t want something that will cheat the test as I still want the same comparable, accurate results, just without the minute of waiting before I get them. I guess you could say I’m asking if anyone knows how to implement a form of time warp.

**Background Info:**

I’m currently working with an object that can count up or down, and then does an action when the desired time has elapsed. All of my tests pass, so I’m completely fine on that front. My problem is that the tests require various lengths of time to pass for the tests to be completely thorough. This isn’t a problem for short tests, say five seconds, but if I wish to test longer lengths of time, say sixty seconds or longer, I have to wait that long before I get my result.

I’m using longer lengths of time on some tests to see how accurate the timing is, and if I’ve made sure the logic is correct so rollover isn’t an issue. I’ve essentially found that, while a short duration of time is fine for the majority of the tests, there are a few that have to be longer.

I’ve been googling and regardless of what search terms I’ve used, I can’t seem to find an answer to a question such as this. The only ones that seem to pop up are "getting up to speed with unit tests" and others of that nature. I’m currently using the MSTestv2 framework that comes with VS2017 if that helps.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**

Thanks for the responses! I appreciate the info I've been given so far and it's nice to get a fresh perspective on how I could tackle the issue. If anyone else has anything they'd like to / want to add, I'm all ears!

Comment: Inject the timer. The mocked timer will notify on a manual call from the test method, the real when the time has passed

Comment: It is unfortunate that people want to break due-diligence by [mocking functionality](https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2016/05/25/have-you-unit-tested-that-aileron-servo/), but now you want to fake _performance testing_ without cheating? Impossible! If something usually takes a minute, then it is going to take a minute.  Anything less means just that.   If when testing an escalator normally takes a minute to raise someone 1 floor but you want it in 1 second, lets hope the person doesn't get flung through the roof

Answer (score 1):

In 1998, [John Carmack wrote](http://archives.seul.org/linuxgames/Oct-1998/msg00123.html):

> If you don't consider time an input value, think about it until you do -- it is an important concept

The basic idea here being that your *logic* is going to take time as an input, and your boundary is going to have an element that can integrate with the clock.

In C#, the result is probably going to look like ports and adapters; you have a port (interface) that describes how you want to interact with the clock, and an adapter (implementation) that implements the interface and reads times off of the clock that you will use in production.

In your unit tests, you *replace* the production adapter with an implementation that you control.

Key idea:

> There are two ways of constructing a software design: One way is to make it so simple that there are obviously no deficiencies

Your adapter implementation should be so simple (by design) that you can just look at it and evaluate its correctness.  No logic, no data transformations, just the simplest thing that could possibly insulate you from the boundary.

Note that this might be a significant departure from your current design.  That's OK, and part of the point of test driven design; the difficulties in testing are supposed to help you recognize the separable responsibilities in your code, and create the correct boundaries around them.

Cory Benfield's talk on [building protocol libraries the right way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Evchk7aNKdQ) describes this approach in the context of reading data from a socket; read data from IO, and just copy the bytes as is into a state machine that performs all of the logic.

So your "clock" might actually just be a stream/sequence of timestamp events, and your unit tests then document "given this sequence of timestamps, then that is the expected behavior of the functional core".

The slower tests, that actually interact with the real clock, are moved from the unit test suite to the integration suite.  They still have value, and you still want them to pass, but you don't want the delays they produce to interrupt the development/refactoring workflow.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I'm not necessarily new to programming, but I still have a lot to learn. This gave me some better ideas about how I could potentially tackle the issue. Maybe reformatting the tests is the best idea rather than figuring out a way to "warp time". It's always nice to get a different perspective on things!